# How to extend Devise Lockable to IP

Tags: ruby

I have an app that uses devise and currently locks people out if they try to login with the wrong password a number of times. I want to extend it to lock a user out if they are accessing from a different IP as well with the help of trackable. Is there a good way to go about this with devise?

Answer (score 1):

Devise itself doesn't do this, but it gives you the information you need to do this on your own with an IP block list table.